Python Tkinter FAIL
I am making my first blog ever in Python and I came up to an error that I can't fix while using an animation,
I divided every page of my blog with a function and right now I am working in the explore page
def explore_hub():
for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    app = customtkinter.CTk()
    app.title("app")
    app.geometry("1240x800")

    # Define the second button (search) with specific dimensions
    button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=700, height=30, text="search!...", command=lambda: on_search_click(button2))
    button2.place(x=300, y=0)

    # Create the search bar with initial width of 0 and height of 30
    search_bar = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=app, width=0, height=30)

    # Variable to track the state of the search bar (hidden or visible)
    is_search_bar_visible = False

    # Function to animate the search bar expansion
    def animate_search_bar_in(target_width, increment=10):
        current_width = search_bar.winfo_width()

        # Check if the current width is less than the target width
        if current_width < target_width:
            new_width = min(current_width + increment, target_width)
            search_bar.configure(width=new_width)

            # Continue the animation until the target width is reached
            app.after(10, animate_search_bar_in, target_width, increment)

    # Function to animate the search bar collapsing
    def animate_search_bar_out(increment=10):
        current_width = search_bar.winfo_width()

        # Check if the current width is greater than 0
        if current_width > 0:
            new_width = max(current_width - increment, 0)
            search_bar.configure(width=new_width)

            # Continue the animation until the width is reduced to 0
            app.after(10, animate_search_bar_out, increment)
        else:
            search_bar.place_forget()  # Remove the search bar from the screen

    # Function to handle button2 click event
    def on_search_click(button):
        nonlocal is_search_bar_visible
        if is_search_bar_visible:
            # Animate the search bar out
            animate_search_bar_out()
            is_search_bar_visible = False
        else:
            # Define the target width and height for the search bar
            target_width = 700
            target_height = 30

            # Place the search bar 5 pixels below the button
            search_bar.place(x=button.winfo_x(), y=button.winfo_y() + button.winfo_height() + 5)
            search_bar.configure(height=target_height)  # Ensure height is set
            animate_search_bar_in(target_width)  # Start the animation
            is_search_bar_visible = True

    # Rest of the GUI components
    button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=100, height=50, text="back to menu", text_color="yellow")
    button1.place(x=0, y=0)

    framewidgets = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app, width=840, height=695)
    framewidgets.place(x=400, y=100)

    buttonfollower = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=210, height=50, text="friends/followers")
    buttonfollower.place(x=400, y=750)

    buttonforum = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=210, height=50, text="forums!")
    buttonforum.place(x=620, y=750)  # 400 + 210 + 10 (previous x + width + gap)

    buttonrequests = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=210, height=50, text="friend requests/add")
    buttonrequests.place(x=840, y=750)  # 620 + 210 + 10

    buttonpost = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=180, height=50, text="Post something!")
    buttonpost.place(x=1060, y=750)

    buttonsubmit1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=300, height=300)
    buttonsubmit1.place(x=710, y=100)

    buttonsubmit2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=220, height=300)
    buttonsubmit2.place(x=1020, y=100)

    buttonsubmit3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=300, height=300)
    buttonsubmit3.place(x=400, y=100)

    buttonsubmit4 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=300, height=300)
    buttonsubmit4.place(x=710, y=425)

    buttonsubmit5 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=220, height=300)
    buttonsubmit5.place(x=1020, y=425)

    buttonsubmit6 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=300, height=300)
    buttonsubmit6.place(x=400, y=425)

This is what looks like my explore page, I tought the error came from the animation I don't understand what's wrong (ignore the variable names)
I tried to enter on explore page but this happens
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2371234244352update"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2371234243584check_dpi_scaling"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed



Please create a minimally reproducible example with correct indentation that reproduces your problem.
